# Posting localized Date formats in ASP.net core with bootstrap datepicker

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-datetimepicker

We currently use bootstrap datepicker in our asp.net core application to select dates that essentially are localized. So I've added all the locale files for the specific languages and these all work fine until I issue a form submit.
For instance say the locale is `es` for spanish with a date like `27 OKT 2021` I get an error RE:
`The date is not a valid date`
How can I convert this back to say `en-GB` on post so that my model stays valid ?

see the settings for my datepicker in the cshtml view below:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
                //format: "dd M yyyy",
                language:  "@CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.ToString()",
                weekStart: 1,
                maxViewMode: 2,
                todayHighlight: true,
                startDate: startDate,
                daysOfWeekDisabled: [],
                showOnfocus: true,
                autoClose: true,
                orientation: "bottom"
            });
```

I also have a  date format set in the cshtml view like so :

```
asp-format="{0:dd MMM yyyy}
```

Answer (score 1):

A best practice for working with dates and times is to use ISO 8601 formats, which are standard and universal. This way you avoid localization problems and only store unambiguous dates and times.

For dates, the format is:

`YYYY-MM-DD`

In JavaScript you can convert a `Date` object to ISO format using `toISOString()`. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).